# Tuple Equivalence and Referencing in Python

Tags: python, memory, reference, tuples

Suppose I had a file with:

```
apple,1,2,3
banana,1,2
orange,1,2,3
pineapple,1
watermelon,1,2,3
```

And my code was:

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self,str):
        values = str.split(",")
        self._name = values[0]
        self._list = tuple(values[1:])

fruits = []
for line in file:
    fruits.append(Fruit(line))
```

I assume apple, orange, and watermelon objects would each have a tuple, they would be equal to each other, but are stored in distinct memory locations. If I had a similar file with 100,000+ lines, and if tuples with the same contents in the same order occurs a lot, how would I best optimize it so that when I parse the file fruits would reference the same memory location?

UPDATE:

Reading comments, is everyone saying I should do this:

```
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self,name,items):
        values = str.split(",")
        self._name = name
        self._items = items

fruits = []
values_list = []
for line in file:
    values = line.split(",")
    name = line[0]
    values = set(line[1:])
    if values in values_list:
        fruits.append(Fruit(name,values_list[values_list.index(values)]))
    else:
        values_list.append(values)
        fruits.append(Fruit(name,values))
```

Seems kind of ugly...?

Comment: Keep them in a `set` and implement `__hash__` on the `Fruit` class.

Comment: you can build a dict so you store only keys rather than complete values

Comment: I mean, each of the 100,000 fruits would be unique (different names) but 50,000 of them may have the same list. So a set or dictionary of fruits wouldn't help.

Comment: So, you want a dict containing _references_ to some tuples stored somewhere else (in a list for example?)

Comment: Updated original post.